# Angular Select Tags

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a select tag in angular. According to many sites I have read and some posts on here, it says when using the select tag to not use "ng-repeat" on the option tag but use "ng-options" on the select tag so that is how I set it up.  My question is, I want a specific option tag selected by default, how do i set the selected attribute using this method?

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_group" ng-change="new_group($event)" ng-options="group as (group.group_name | decodeuri) for group in groups"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a default is easy: set `selected_group` equal to a particular group in your controller.

The basic idea is that you have a collection and the selected option is to be stored in your `ng-model`. To designate a selection from the start, you need to put something in `ng-model`. That would have to be in your controller.

Comment: How? i tried ng-init="selected_group=1" and that does not work.

Comment: Not through ng-init. In your controller, do something like `$scope.selected_group = $scope.groups[0];`

Comment: ng-init shouldn't be used the way @LJ.Wizard suggests: see the red warning in the docs here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: Here is part of my dilemma  The select tag I am using is using a directive.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `<option>` tag:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected_group" ng-change="new_group(selected_group)" ng-options="group as (group.group_name | decodeuri) for group in groups">
    <option value="">Please Select an Option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created small working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amighty/mhsy3np8/32/)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select class="form-control" ng-model="option.group" ng-options="group as (group.name | myfilter) for group in groups">  
</select>
</div>


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('myfilter', function() {
  return function(v) {
    return v == 'test3' ? 'filtered test3' : v;
  };
});
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {      

$scope.groups = [{id:1,name:'test1', phone:'1234567890'},
                       {id:2,name:'test2', phone:'1234567890'},
                       {id:3,name:'test3', phone:'1234567890'}
                     ];

$scope.option={                     
    group: $scope.groups[1]
  }                    

});
```